# Running Perl script to call webpages through DOS command prompt?

Tags: windows, perl, windows-xp, dos

My workplace uses XP and I was trying to run the following script on it

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get( 'http://google.com' );

$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 0,
    fields      => {
        q       => 'led zeppelin',
    }
);

print $mech->content;
```

However, when I try to run the script through DOS, I always get an error message saying that the page cannot be loaded because my computer can't connect to google.com:80 because of a timeout.

As far as I know, this is not an internet problem, because my browser seems to be running fine. What I want to know is, are there any other permissions or parameters to be set so the site can be loaded? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: Google's terms of service forbid what you are doing, and **will block you** from automated scraping. Use their [search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) instead.

Comment: I assume you don't really mean that you tried to run this in MS-DOS?  You're talking about the Windows command prompt, cmd.exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the Internet can only be accessed through a proxy server in your workplace, which is a common practice.

```
$mech->proxy(['http', 'ftp'], 'http://proxy.example.com:8000/');
```

See [*How do I use WWW::Mechanize through a proxy server?* in `WWW::Mechanize::FAQ`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFAQ#How-do-I-use-WWW%3a%3aMechanize-through-a-proxy-server-).